# How to get two strings from a single input (words separated by a space)

Tags: computer-science

I am trying to create two strings from a single input.

So if the user inputs "John Doe" I want to have two strings J and D where J=John and D=Doe.

I tried using the scanner.nextLine() method but that won't let me create two strings from the single input.

So essentially I want to create another string whenever the user inputs a space between words.

If anyone can clear that up for me that would be wonderful! I have just started studying computer science so this is all new to me.

Comment: Can u give more information like what language of console application you are writing？

Comment: What have you tried. Also, your tag is inappropriate. Lastly, you'll likely want to split the string at the white space and create and array. If you wish to map them then I suggest a hashmap where the key is the first letter of the split object and the value the object itself.

Comment: Sorry I am using java. I am using BlueJ

Answer (score 1):

To get two strings from a single input (words separated by a space) follow this step.

1) First of all split the string
2) store with index
3) print with single space

```java
public class SpaceRemove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "The   java      is   best";
        String[] temp3 = s.split("\\s+"); // First step
        String a, b, c, d;
        a = temp3[0]; // Store "The" at index 0
        b = temp3[1]; // Store "java" at index 1
        c = temp3[2]; // Store "is" at index 2
        d = temp3[3]; // Store "best" at index 3
        for (String string : temp3) {
            System.out.println(" " + string.trim()); // Print the split string
        }
        System.out.println("You input: " + a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d); // Print the result with equal space
                                                                                // between two string.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is split a string.Im assuming you are using java you can simply take your string and do:

```
String ex = "John Doe";
String[] parts = String.split(ex);
String part1 = array[0];
String part2 = array[1];
```